# Getting error KeyError: 'name_long' for 'country' 'records' object "name = country.attributes['name_long']"

Tags: python, heatmap, cartopy

I got his example to try from another page "[Make colorbar legend in Matplotlib/Cartopy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41291534/make-colorbar-legend-in-matplotlib-cartopy)" but when I am trying to run it in Jupyter Notebook it throws errors like this:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-55c282431f2e> in <module>()
     14 ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.Robinson())
     15 for country in shpreader.Reader(countries_shp).records():
---> 16     name = country.attributes['name_long']
     17     num_users = countries[name]
     18     ax.add_geometries(country.geometry, ccrs.PlateCarree(),

KeyError: 'name_long'
```

Please help! Code sample:

```
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.io.shapereader as shpreader
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy as np

cmap = mpl.cm.Blues
# Countries is a dictionary of {"country_name": number of users}, for example
countries = {"United States": 100, "Canada": 50, "China": 10}

max_users = float(max(countries.values()))
shapename = 'admin_0_countries'
countries_shp = shpreader.natural_earth(resolution='110m', category='cultural', name=shapename)
ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.Robinson())
for country in shpreader.Reader(countries_shp).records():
    name = country.attributes['name_long']
    num_users = countries[name]
    ax.add_geometries(country.geometry, ccrs.PlateCarree(),
                facecolor=cmap(num_users/max_users, 1))

plt.savefig('iOS_heatmap.png', transparent=True, dpi=900)
```

Comment: When I log keys, it has a key 'name_long':
print(sorted(country.attributes.keys()))

['ABBREV', ... 'NAME', 'NAME_ALT', 'NAME_CIAWF', 'NAME_LEN', 'NAME_LONG', 'NAME_SORT', 'NOTE_ADM0', 'NOTE_BRK', 'POP_EST', ...'WOE_NOTE', 'featurecla', 'scalerank']

Comment: `NAME_LONG` is not the same thing as `name_long`

Comment: At some point the Natural Earth metadata has changed, and the key names   have been modified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your country.attributes dictionary/map does not have a value for the key `'name_long'`.

Your country is a [`Record`](http://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/v0.15/tutorials/using_the_shapereader.html#cartopy.io.shapereader.Record) as given by the [documentation for shapereader](http://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/v0.15/tutorials/using_the_shapereader.html).

Records have Attributes which is just a plain dictionary. Whatever data you are reading does not have a `'name_long'` attribute.

You appear to be [downloading the data](http://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/v0.15/tutorials/using_the_shapereader.html#cartopy.io.shapereader.natural_earth) from the [`NaturalEarthData`](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/) website. So check to see what attributes are actually available from there.

As per your comment, you appear to have the `'NAME_LONG'` key, but... `'NAME_LONG' != 'name_long'`